# Is there any trustworthy gems for multi table inheritance in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've scourded the internet but can not find a gem that is good on multi table inheritance. I am just wondering does anyone know of any out there at the moment?

Comment: http://mediumexposure.com/multiple-table-inheritance-active-record/

Comment: That is a good way, but I was just wondering was there any ruby gems